# СПП с условным придаточным или нет?

Tags: синтаксис

> *Если бы можно было вот так до рассвета сидеть и молчать, да только
>   завтра на работу*.

Не могу решить, надо считать это предложение как СПП с условным придаточным.

Колеблюсь, потому что нет обеих частей условия, а только протазис (где сослагательное наклонение используется для выражения желания, если я правильно понимаю).

С другой стороны, не уверена, можно развернуть его в:

"*Если бы завтра не надо было на работу, герой сидел бы с героиней до рассвета и молчал бы*"?

Как Вы считаете, условное или нет?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если бы можно было вот так до рассвета сидеть и молчать, да только завтра на работу.-сложносочинённое предложение, где первое предложение - независимая конструкция с союзом если с желательным значением.

(Сравним: О Боже, если б сейчас упасть мёртвой. [В. Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба])

СПП было бы в таком виде:"Хорошо было бы, если бы можно было вот так до рассвета сидеть и молчать".

Answer (score 3):

**Если бы можно было вот так до рассвета сидеть и молчать, да только завтра на работу.**

1) Тип предложения: сложносочиненное с противительным союзом (ДА=НО). Такие предложения относят к предложениям **неоднородного состава**, то есть в них между частями сложного предложения существуют **зависимые отношения**, как и в сложноподчиненном предложении. В первой части выражено **желательное условие**, а во второй части сообщается о невозможности выполнения желания.

2) **О желательном значении сослагательного наклонения**

**Независимые конструкции** с ЕСЛИ БЫ  часто упоминаются, когда речь идет о
**желательном значении сослагательного наклонения.** Они омонимичны протазису (первой части) условного предложения с **опущенным** аподозисом (выводом, следствием). **Вот если бы вы видели его на репетициях!  –  Вот если бы вы видели его на репетициях, вы бы поняли.**  Такие конструкции связаны с выражением неосуществимого желания и имеют оттенок сожаления говорящего о том, что некоторая желательная  возможность была упущена или  отсутствует. https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/06/29/1115923238/dobrushina.pdf

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это не СПП, а ССП: между предложениями нет подчинительной связи. Их легко оформить как два самостоятельных предложения: ***Если бы можно было вот так до рассвета сидеть и молчать!***  ***Да только завтра на работу.***